# bpy.ops.object.align( align_mode='OPT_4' ) throws: keyword "align_mode" unrecognized

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to correctly specify what is written in the blender [API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.align).   I'm coding:

```
bpy.ops.object.align( align_mode='OPT_4' )
```

but get the console error message:

```
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "align_mode" unrecognized
```

The [API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.align) explains the "align_mode":

```
bpy.ops.object.align(bb_quality=True, align_mode='OPT_2', relative_to='OPT_4', align_axis={})

Align objects

Parameters
        bb_quality (boolean, (optional)) – High Quality, Enables high quality calculation of the bounding box for perfect results on complex shape meshes with rotation/scale (Slow)

        align_mode (enum in ['OPT_1', 'OPT_2', 'OPT_3'], (optional)) – Align Mode, Side of object to use for alignment

        relative_to (enum in ['OPT_1', 'OPT_2', 'OPT_3', 'OPT_4'], (optional)) –

        Relative To, Reference location to align to

            OPT_1 Scene Origin, Use the scene origin as the position for the selected objects to align to.

            OPT_2 3D Cursor, Use the 3D cursor as the position for the selected objects to align to.

            OPT_3 Selection, Use the selected objects as the position for the selected objects to align to.

            OPT_4 Active, Use the active object as the position for the selected objects to align to.

        align_axis (enum set in {'X', 'Y', 'Z'}, (optional)) – Align, Align to axis
```

My script (for context):

```
import bpy

## replace imported Mesh Text (selected) with real (editable) Text aligned to old that gets deleted
oldObjects = bpy.context.selected_objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all( action='DESELECT' ) # Deselect all objects

for oldObj in oldObjects:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all( action='DESELECT' ) # Deselect all objects
    bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=oldObj.location, scale=(1, 1, 1))
    
    # Delete last 4 letters from template "Text" to leave a single Letter "T"
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.font.delete(type='PREVIOUS_OR_SELECTION')
    bpy.ops.font.delete(type='PREVIOUS_OR_SELECTION')
    bpy.ops.font.delete(type='PREVIOUS_OR_SELECTION')
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    
    # align new letter to old mesh
    print( oldObj.name + str( oldObj.location ) )
    oldObj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.align( align_mode='OPT_4' )

    # delete oldObj
    bpy.ops.object.select_all( action='DESELECT' ) # Deselect all objects
    oldObj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

and yes I know I could replace the align() with:

```
bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=oldObj.location, rotation=oldObj.rotation_euler )
```

but I want to understand better how understand blender API documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To track down the cause of  the error shown :**.

- Could be a version issue, the docs linked are for current,  matching
  those available circa 2.91
- If you are using an older version, consult the appropriate version
  docs, or consult the python console.

  ```
   >>> bpy.ops.object.align(

   align()
   bpy.ops.object.align(
           bb_quality=True,    
           align_mode='OPT_2',
           relative_to='OPT_4',
           align_axis=set()
           )
   Align Objects
  ```

and to quickly see the valid values of any argument, crunch in an invalid one as shown above with `align_mode='FOO'`.

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.align(align_mode='OPT_4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/batfinger/blender/vers/blender-2.91.2-linux64/2.91/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  enum "FOO" not found in ('OPT_1', 'OPT_2', 'OPT_3')

    >>> bpy.ops.object.align(align_mode='OPT_4')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/batfinger/blender/vers/blender-2.91.2-linux64/2.91/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  enum "OPT_4" not found in ('OPT_1', 'OPT_2', 'OPT_3')
```

- It could be the case some addon you have enabled has overridden the
  default operator.
- As displayed above this will be evident by typing
  `bpy.ops.object.align(` to autocomplete, into python console to
  display the operator docstring

**With API calls (*ie* no operators).**

As is the case for most operators can be replaced with API calls.

*eg* Here I've simply placed a text object, each sharing the data (single letter "T") at global location of each of the selected objects, before removing.  Changing transform  based on whatever the desired align operator properties would be little to no hassle.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
# font
font = bpy.data.curves.new("Foo", 'FONT')
font.body = "T"

for ob in context.selected_objects:
    text = bpy.data.objects.new("Text", font)
    text.matrix_world = ob.matrix_world
    context.collection.objects.link(text)
    bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)
```

Comment: I will look over your solution, however you overlook that it is the keyword, not its value, that is the cause of the error.  Even when i use "bpy.ops.object.align(bb_quality=True, align_mode='OPT_2', relative_to='OPT_4')", I get ``keyword "bb_quality" unrecognized``, or whatever keyword I use first!   I am trying to understand why I cannot seem to understand the documentation in general in these cases, and it is slowing down my ability to learn the bpy python methods.  I am using v2.91

Comment: Also now that I think over my comment above, there might be some other *.align method that I'm invoking that doesn't have these keyword params...?

Comment: @james_t as displayed in answer, in python console type `bpy.ops.object.align(`<TAB> to autocomplete to display the operator docstring (which will have the keywords) In case some addon has overridden the default operator.

Comment: interesting.  I only get the no-arg version!  :
```
>>> bpy.ops.object.align(
align()
bpy.ops.object.align()
Align Selected To Active
>>> bpy.ops.object.align(
```
and ... how ugly that I can only do this in the console, and not in the editor, although there is a (non-functional) auto-complete under the Edit menu item

Comment: @james_t just asked https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215966/finding-which-addon-an-operator-belongs-to in relation to this.  Couple of scripts to run to find if there is an addon overriding the usual suspect align operator.

Comment: Thanks to all!  It's time for this retired/confused java programmer to take a blender python tutorial !!!

Comment: In console I def do NOT get the documented version of align(keyword_args...```
>>> bpy.ops.object.align(
align()
bpy.ops.object.align()
Align Selected To Active
``` (v 2.91, 2.92)