# Finding which addon an operator belongs to

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

A [recent question / answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215915/bpy-ops-object-align-align-mode-opt-4-throws-keyword-align-mode-unrecogn) involves what looks like an overridden operator:

```
bpy.ops.object.align()
```

Differing from the documented default, how do we find which addon(s) have registered the operator.

**Method 1:**

Edit to match operator id.

```
op_name = "import_scene.obj"
```

Script:

```
import addon_utils
from bpy.types import Operator
from importlib import import_module
import inspect

op_name = "import_scene.obj"

for m in addon_utils.modules():
    name = m.__name__
    default, loaded = addon_utils.check(name)
    if loaded:
        mod = import_module(name)
        classes = getattr(mod, "classes", [])
        for c in classes:
            if (
                issubclass(c, Operator) 
                and  
                getattr(c, "bl_idname", "").startswith(op_name)
                ):
                print(name)
        
        if not classes:
            for k in dir(mod):
                cls = getattr(mod, k, None)
                if inspect.isclass(cls) and issubclass(cls, Operator):
                    id = getattr(cls, "bl_idname", "")
                    if id.startswith(op_name):
                        print(name)
```

By either looking at the addons `classes` or inspecting all objects of enabled addons.  [How do I run an existing add-on via the python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164230/how-do-i-run-an-existing-add-on-via-the-python-api)

**Method 2:**

This approach disable, check op is still registered, re-enable...

Edit your operator of interest into

```
op_id = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj.idname()
```

Script:

```
import addon_utils
import bpy

op_id = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj.idname()

for m in addon_utils.modules():
    name = m.__name__
    default, loaded = addon_utils.check(name)
    if loaded:
        addon_utils.disable(name)
        if not hasattr(bpy.types, op_id):
            print(name)
            #addon_utils.enable(name)
            #break
        addon_utils.enable(name)
```

How would you approach finding an operators registering addon(s) from its id name?.

Note: *don't save preferences after running this, as addon preferences could be lost after disable.*

Comment: for me, on script 1:  line 15: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: Have put in fix for that, prob could flag it since it is "usual practice" to have a tuple for a "bl_idname"

Comment: super! thanks,  unfortunately ```op_name = "bpy.ops.object.align"``` returns nothing for me, nor does ```op_name = "bpy"``` !

Comment: ah i changed to ```op_name in getattr(c, "bl_idname", "")``` and now ```op_name = "align"``` returned "space_view3d_align_tools", so this is getting me what I need to know.  Perhaps I would disable this add-on to help solve my problem.  thanks again!!!